# how to prompt user to save a pdf file to his local machine in django?

Tags: django, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am fairly new to Django and my project requires me to prompt user to open a pdf upon clicking a link. I already have the pdf file on my local machine and dont want to recreate it using Reportlab. Is there any way to do it?

I tried

```py
with open("/user/some/directory/somefilename.pdf") as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
        return response
```

but it returned 404 page not found as the requested url wasn't in the URLconf of myproject.urls

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that worked for me is by using FileSystemStorage

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse

fs = FileSystemStorage("/Users/location/where/file/is_saved/")      
with fs.open("somefile.pdf") as pdf:
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="my_pdf.pdf"'
    return response
```

and now its prompting the user to save the file as it normally would!

Answer (score 0):

In general, when user click "Download", you can:

```
- If file is not existed:
    - Generate pdf file use ReportLab as you did.
    - Store generated file to a public dir.
return HttpResponseRedirect(file_url_to_public_dir)
```